# Easiest Way to Reset Bootstrap CSS attributes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar created using Twitter Bootstrap:

```
<div class="navbar-inner navlinks">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ouvrez</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Decouvrir</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can override the font colors, padding, etc. easily enough by changing attributes in my `navlink` class. However, links within a navbar list such as this have a ton of text shadowing/gradient attributes by default in Twitter Bootstrap. Is the only way to override these to set each attribute to some default level, or is there something in CSS that will allow me to restore the "regular" settings in one fell swoop?

Comment: don't change bootstrap style but you can call your style sheet after bootstrap.css, it will override style bootstrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the following way :

Create a `new css file` and place it after the bootstrap.css file so that it can override any default property you dont wanna use .Like the example below :-

```
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now to remove any `background` `box-shadow` or `border property` and `border-radius`, on your navbar you can do the following :

```
.navbar-inner{
 background:none;
 filter:none;
 box-shadow:none;
 border-radius:0px;
 border:none;
}
```

To customize `navbar links`, you can do the following(set any values here or any new property here will override the default) :

```
.navbar .nav > li > a{

    padding:5px;
text-shadow:none;
  }
```

To customize `hover` and on `focus` styles :

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
     color: #333333;
     text-decoration: none;
     background-color: transparent;
 }
```

To customize `active` class for links :

```
.navbar .nav .active > a{
color:#ccc;
background:none;
box-shadow:none;
   }

 .navbar .nav .active > a:hover{
background:none;
box-shadow:none;
   }
```

Comment: Brilliant, a huge improvement on the overides I was using. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There was a video about this (I just found out about Bootstrap a few days ago) and they explained to not alter the supplied css and instead override the css in your own stylesheet.  They also mentioned this stylesheet has to come AFTER the bootstrap style sheet is called in order for the override to work, and you of course would call the same names in your override.  The video was on Pluralsight.

P.S.  I ended up altering the css for navbar in the main css since I'm in the "playing" stage.  Also, bootstrap has it's own css it applies for images for your entire page, so watch out for that.